# Cannot claim the only interface I can see through device.configuration.interfaces

Tags: google-chrome, barcode, barcode-scanner, reader, webusb

Trying to read USB Barcode Scanner on MacOS `10.14.1` in Google Chrome Version `71.0.3578.98` via WebUSB.

Using a barcode scanner: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Barcode-Scanner-USB-Handheld-Wired-Portable-Laser-Scan-Bar-Code-Reader-Scan-POS/282865082953

Device is visible in the requestDevice dialog as `Usb211` and opens successfully, code I used for this here:

```
const VENDOR_ID = 0x8888

navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: VENDOR_ID }] })
.then(selectedDevice => {
  device = selectedDevice;
  return device.open();
})
.then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
.then(() => device.claimInterface(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber)) # interfaceNumber is 0 
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

When I tried to `claimInterface(0)` (which is the only interface available in the `device` object, it fails with the error `An attempt to claim a USB device interface has been blocked because it implements a protected interface class.` (or `SecurityError` DOMException `The requested interface implements a protected class.`) - this one is expected because of the recent changes: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/LZXocaeCwDw/GLfAffGLAAAJ

Is there any way to "debug deeper" somehow because I cannot see a way to use only available interface.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the only available interface is blocked then there is no way to use it through the WebUSB API. There is a separate API in the works, [WebHID](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5172464636133376), that is designed to satisfy the particular requirements when granting access to devices that provide an HID interface.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, solution was easier, will post it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by switching scanner into different interface - there are 4 interface modes and one of them ("USB VCOM") allows to have 2 interfaces available, so `claimInterface(1)` was successful.